# SQL Server Edition included with Team Foundation Server 2013

Tags: tfs

I am trying to determine what SQL Server edition will be installed with Team Foundation Server 2013 if it is installed on Windows Server 2012 R2 using the Standard Configuration.  The install guide is vague about this.  Will it be Express or Standard?  It appears to be different than with TFS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the basic configuration of Team Foundation Server, automatically with SQL Server Express SP1.
or install manually other versions.
link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd631889.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Only the Basic Configuration of TFS 2013 automatically installs SQL Server and it installs the Express version. This from:

[Sql Server Requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631889.aspx)

From the same article: You can pre-install one of the supported editions Sql2012.sp1+ or Sql2014

During installation, you are required to select a configuration (basic, standard etc). If you choose standard and the installer can't find an existing SQL Server instance you can not proceed.